# Banner A is displayed on pageA.html and bannerB with pageB.html

Tags: javascript, if-statement, banner

I want to display bannerA.js when visitor is on page.html, and display bannerB.js when visitor is on page_en.html and so on with 5 banner/5 page.

I saw i could use some code like this :
if(document.URL.indexOf("foo_page.html") >= 0){ 
...show your message
}

but I'm not sure because I have more than two choices. Maybe switch control can help ?

How can I do this using the same javascript code ?

Comment: Why do you want to use the same code instead of writing a seperate .js for each page?

Comment: I use wysiwyg software and when i activate multilangage, it will create page.html and page_en.html for english and so on for other langage. My problem is whith multilangage mode it allow me to change text but not visual element like flash banner. So I need one code to display different banner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'll do:

```
   var parts = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '').split('/'),
       page = parts[parts.length - 1];

    switch (page)
    {
    case "index.html":
      //Banner 1
      break;
    case "index_en.html":
      //Banner 2
      break;
    }
```

page will hold the string you are interested in and then do a switch accordingly.

Comment: Ok good but i'm not sure how to use it. I have following pages : index.html ; index_en.html ; index_de.html ; index_ro.html;

banner is a .js file that is introduce with the following code :
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://monsite.fr/banniere.js"></script><noscript><p style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;padding:1em;">Votre navigateur ne supporte pas le Javascript ou a été désactivé.</p></noscript><div id="123456"></div><div id="123456"></div>

can you help me introducing it so that it work in a html code form

Comment: Updated example according to your pages

Comment: Hey thanks a lot !!

It's working excepted I can't insert my banner correctly. My code to insert is this way actually : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://monsite.fr/banniere.js"></script><noscript><p style="background-color:#ffffff;color:#000000;padding:1em;">Votre navigateur ne supporte pas le Javascript ou a été désactivé.</p></noscript><div id="123456"></div><div id="123456"></div> Any idea ? I think I get close & thanks again

Comment: you can't use script tags in JS use $.getScript('url'); instead

Answer (score 0):

it is not a best practice to rely on **document.URL.indexOf("foo_page.html")**, that is because you can have the 'foo_page.html' as an url parameter (**http://some/somepage.html?filter=true&foo_page.html**)

you can use the window.location object that exposes the 'pathname'... [see more on this here](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location)

```
window.location.pathname.indexOf("foo_page.html")
```

Comment: I don't have part like http://some/somepage.html?filter=true&foo_page.html because it's a static website and I choose myself the name of the page

Comment: @user1829621 and yet people may decide to play with the URL.